# How to ask for user input when defining VSCode's custom command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm defining a custom command in the `package.json` file:

```js
[...]
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "daps.validate.DCfile",
        "title": "DAPS: Validate with DC file"
      }
    ],
[...]
```

in the `extension.js` file, there's going to be a function:

```js
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('daps.validate.DCfile', function () {
//ADD ME        
});
```

inside this function, how do i ask for user input similar to the `"inputs":` key of the `tasks.json` file? BTW I'm going to run shell commands inside these defined commands.

Comment: use `QuickInput` and `QuickPick`, do a search on the API page

Comment: for complex input use a webview